# Establish communication between two separate flows

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

So I am working on a simple server for my application. The basic purpose of this server is to listen to request, understand it, forward the request to the domain (an object within the server) which then interacts with the file system to create some objects and return data to where the request came from.

So far, I have come up with design like this:
[image]

So what I have done, is to start a service which has a **Connector** and an **Engine**.

- The **Connector** has multiple protocol handlers that handle a specified protocol. Each protocol handler initializes an *Endpoint Listener* which opens a socket and listens to incoming requests.
- The **Engine** has multiple domains, where each domain has its designated directory on the file system to read/write data.

I am able to initialize the **Service** layer including all its object, but I am not able to figure out what can I do to make the *Connector* and *Engine* to be able to exchange data.

## Here comes the complexiy.

It is not fixed that the Service would have only one connector, or the Engine would have only one Domain, or the Connector would have only one Protocol Handler. Eveything is configured through an XML file. The server could run multiple services as well.

Also, the Connector must not be aware of the engine, so that it could not be directly notified.

## Additional information that could be useful.

- Everything in the diagram has a Lifecycle (**EXCEPT PROTOCOL HANDLERS AND ENDPOINT**) that is `init() -> start() -> stop() -> destroy()`. A listener could be added to listen to change in lifecycle states.
- The possible lifecycle states are `NEW, BEFORE_INIT, INITIALIZING, INITIALIZED, AFTER_INIT, BEFORE_START, STARTING, STARTED, AFTER_START, BEFORE_STOP, STOPPING, STOPPED, AFTER_STOP, BEFORE_DESTORY, DESTROYING, DESTROYED, AFTER_DESTROY`.
- There would always be only one engine.
- The server runs as a thread, so it should be thread safe.
- I have interfaces for each object visible in the diagram.

---

I dont know whether it is a good question or not, or the implementation is not as confusing as I think, but I would like to know what other people think could be a good way to do this...

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: I want the engine to handle the request when the endpoint receives it...

Comment: and what's the big concern? you want the two components to be decoupled?

Comment: Yea. But there has to be atleast one connector which opens a socket (on port 80) and any incoming requests should be handled by the engine while keeping the connector unaware of engine.